# User query string in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What is it the best and safe way to get a string from a user and use it in the `WHERE` statement of a query.

Let's say that I have a Model named DB, which contains the columns `c1` and `c2`. I want the user to be able to give me a string like `str="c1: value1"` or `str="c1: value1, c2: value2"` so to use it to perform a find (`DB.find(str)`). Of course I don't want him/her to be able to perform **SQL injection**. Is there an elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important thing to avoid here is putting the user response directly into a where clause. So do not do something like DB.where("c1 = value"). Instead you can rely on rails built in sql sanitizing, by doing something like

DB.where("c1 t = ?", value)

The AR documentation is really clear on this.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions

Comment: Is there an elegant way to check the same value multiple times with this method? Something like DB.where("c1 t=? OR c2 t=?", value, value) (without repeating value many times).

Comment: With sql no. There are other ways though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your *string* format is fixed, then you can convert it to a `Hash`, and then can apply it to the `#where` clause.

```
string = "c1: value1, c2: value2"
hash = Hash[*string.split(/[,:]/).map(&:strip)]
DB.where(hash)
```